# Selenium Webdriver Python for Android - installation of API found on github

Tags: android, python-2.7, installation, selenium-webdriver

[I found this API on github for Selenium Webdriver with Python for Android testing](https://github.com/truebit/AndroidWebDriver4Python). I already have tested Webdriver with Python and have it installed successfully.

First though, is this API necessary? Can Selenium Webdriver test Android using only the Python bindings?

If not, could you look at Step 3 and Step 4 of the installation instructions?

> 1. download AndroidWebDriver4Python using command:
>      `git clone git://github.com/truebit/AndroidWebDriver4Python.git`
> 2. download and extract Selenium Python client
> 3. copy the entire `py` folder under `AndroidWebDriver4Python` to merge the same one in root directory of `AndroidDriver` for Python
> 4. back to the root directory of Selenium Python Client, to install this modified version using command:
>      `python setup.py install`

I don't understand step 3. Don't you need to copy any py files into the Lib folder of your Python27 directory?

Also, doesn't step 4 reinstall your Python instance?